# Difference in outputs between ```pinv``` and ```cg``` in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix-inverse, inverse

I have two arrays `A` and `B`. I am trying to solve for `X` in `AX=B`. I am using `scipy.sparse.linalg.cg` and `np.linalg.pinv`. Both present different outputs which I have shown below. From physics, I know that `X_PINV` is reasonable and `X_CG` is not. Why is this the case? Isn't `scipy.sparse.linalg.cg` better at handling arrays containing many zeros?

```
import numpy as np 

from scipy.sparse import csc_matrix
from scipy.sparse.linalg import cg

A = np.array([[-0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00, -3.14818814e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  3.14818814e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, -6.18884524e-11,
         3.01947672e-11,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  2.96393986e-11,
        -8.85024710e-11,  0.00000000e+00,  2.71693871e-11,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  2.69575828e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00, -2.69575828e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         3.01947672e-11,  0.00000000e+00, -8.80279778e-11,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.82796665e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.95535441e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        -2.82796665e-11,  2.82796665e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  2.71693871e-11,
         2.69985723e-11, -8.37215036e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.95535441e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, -5.94799650e-11,
         3.13938542e-11,  0.00000000e+00,  2.80861108e-11,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  2.75266566e-11,
        -5.56127673e-11,  0.00000000e+00,  2.80861108e-11,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  2.71693871e-11,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.82796665e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00, -1.11175621e-10,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.88894150e-11,  2.68371519e-11,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  2.75266566e-11,
         3.13938542e-11,  0.00000000e+00, -8.65706976e-11,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         2.76501868e-11,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        -2.88894150e-11,  2.88894150e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.95535441e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         3.02211610e-11, -8.66118569e-11,  2.68371519e-11,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.95535441e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.88894150e-11, -8.77051902e-11,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.92622312e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  2.80861108e-11,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        -2.80861108e-11,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  2.68371519e-11,
         0.00000000e+00, -8.51103698e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         2.72797916e-11,  3.09934263e-11,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, -0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.92622312e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
        -8.90230278e-11,  3.09934263e-11,  2.87673703e-11],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  2.92622312e-11,  0.00000000e+00,
         2.72797916e-11, -8.82357080e-11,  0.00000000e+00],
       [ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
         2.72797916e-11,  0.00000000e+00, -2.72797916e-11]])

A1 = csc_matrix(A)

B = np.array([ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00, -1.34636596e-08, -1.34636596e-08,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,
        0.00000000e+00])

X_CG= cg(A1, B)
print("X_CG=",[X_CG])  


X_PINV = np.linalg.pinv(A).dot(B)
print("X_PINV =",[X_PINV])
```

The current output is

```
X_CG= [(array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.,
       0., 0., 0., 0.]), 0)]
X_PINV = [array([ 0.00000000e+00,  0.00000000e+00,  4.02753575e+02,  3.79606697e+02,
        0.00000000e+00,  3.01629821e+02,  2.73930743e+02,  2.73930743e+02,
       -1.23220465e-04, -1.23220465e-04,  2.48466218e+02, -1.23220465e-04,
        2.23084559e+02,  2.23084559e+02,  1.95133829e+02, -1.23220465e-04,
        1.13675879e+02, -1.54346983e-11,  8.87020043e+01,  6.51230912e+01,
        8.87020043e+01])]
```

Comment: Is this true `. A must represent a hermitian, positive definite matrix. `?

Comment: Well I am not sure about that.

Comment: Although, one could argue that `cg(A1, B, tol=1e-30)` provides a better solution than `pinv` in this case.

Comment: Thanks. But using ```tol=1e-30``` for much larger arrays, say ```500x500``` yields null output.

Comment: I suppose it all depends on the gradient. `pinv` results, in this case, look suspicious since some vector elements are many orders of magnitude larger than elements of either `A` or `B`.

Comment: you could try removing the all-zero rows and columns of A

Comment: Doing so wouldn't it alter ```A``` completely and result in the inverse of another array but ```A```?